# How to get the value of id of innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have created a html like this:

```
<body onload = callAlert();loaded()>
<ul id="thelist">
<div id = "lst"></div>          
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

The `callAlert()` is here:

```
function callAlert()
    {
        listRows = prompt("how many list row you want??");
        var listText = "List Number";
                for(var i = 0;i < listRows; i++)
                {
                    if(i%2==0)
                    {
                        listText = listText +i+'<p style="background-color:#EEEEEE" id = "listNum' + i + '" onclick = itemclicked(id)>';
                    }                   
                    else
                    {
                        listText = listText + i+ '<p  id = "listNum' + i + '" onclick = itemclicked(id)>';
                    }                                   
                    listText = listText + i;
                    
                    //document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = listText+i+'5';
                }
                document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = listText+i;
    }
```

**Inside `callAlert()`,** I have created id runtime inside the `<p>` tag and at last of for loop, I have set the paragraph like this. `document.getElementById("lst").innerHTML = listText+i;`

Now I am confuse when `listItem` is clicked then how to access the value of the selected item.

**I am using this:**

```
function itemclicked(id)
    {
        alert("clicked at :"+id);
        var pElement = document.getElementById(id).value;
        alert("value of this is: "+pElement);
    }
```

But getting value as **undefined**.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Slightly unrelated but maybe parse the output from the prompt before entering the loop i.e. `parseInt( listRows, 10 )` and then test `if( listRows ) \\ false if NaN`. Just in case someone enters 'one'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, you should really work on you CodingStyle. Also, write simple, clean code.

First, the html-code should simply look like this:

```
    <body onload="callAlert();loaded();">
        <ul id="thelist"></ul>
    </body>
```

No div or anything like this. `ul` and `ol` shall be used in combination with `li` only. 
Also, you should always close the html-tags in the right order. Otherwise, like in your examle, you have different nubers of opening and closing-tags. (the closing `div` in the 5th line of your html-example doesn't refer to a opening div-tag)...

And here comes the fixed code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function callAlert() {
            var rows = prompt('Please type in the number of required rows');
            var listCode = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                var listID = 'list_' + i.toString();
                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    listCode += '<li style="background-color:#EEEEEE" id="' + listID + '" onclick="itemClicked(this.id);">listItem# ' + i + '</li>';
                }
                else {
                    listCode += '<li id="' + listID + '" onclick="itemClicked(this.id);">listItem# ' + i + '</li>';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('thelist').innerHTML = listCode;
        }

        function itemClicked(id) {
            var pElement = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
            alert("Clicked: " + id + '\nValue: ' + pElement);
        }
    </script>
```

You can watch a working sample in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwYq7/20/).

The problems were:

1. You have to commit the id of the clicked item using `this.id` like @Varada already mentioned.
2. Before that, you have to build a working id, parsing numbers to strings using `.toString()`
3. You really did write kind of messy code. What was supposed to result wasn't a list, it was various `div`-containers wrapped inside a `ul`-tag. Oh my.

BTW: Never ever check if sth. is `0` using the `==`-operator. Better always use the `===`-operator. Read about the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

BTW++: I don't know what `value` you wanted to read in your `itemClicked()`-function. I didn't test if it would read the `innerHTML` but generally, you can only read information from where information was written to before. In this sample, `value` should be empty i guess..

Hope i didn't forget about anything. The Code works right now as you can see. If you've got any further questions, just ask.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes,this is the complete solution of my doubts. Thanks buddy. Thnks a lot

Answer (score 2):

try `onclick = itemclicked(this.id)` instead of `onclick = 'itemclicked(id)'`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass only the var `i` and search the id after like this:

Your p constructor dymanic with passing only `i`

```
<p  id = "listNum' + i + '" onclick = itemclicked(' + i + ')>
```

function

```
function itemclicked(id)
    {
        id='listNum'+i;
        alert("clicked at :"+id);
        var pElement = document.getElementById(id).value;
        alert("value of this is: "+pElement);
    }
```

is what you want?

Comment: getting error at var pElement = document.getElementById(id).value;

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but shouldn't the onclick function be wrapped with double quotes like so:

You have this

```
onclick = itemclicked(id)>'
```

And it should be this

```
onclick = "itemclicked(id)">'
```

You have to modify your itemclicked function to retrieve the "value" of your p element.

```
function itemclicked( id ) {

    alert( "clicked at :" + id );
    var el = document.getElementById( id );

    // depending on the browser one of these will work
    var pElement = el.contentText || el.innerText; 

    alert( "value of this is: " + pElement );
}
```

demo [here](http://jsbin.com/owakeq/3/edit)

Comment: yes it works in both d way.but this is not the solution of my question. and if the onclick have any error then how my alert of the function is executed

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide us with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?